# Debugging ASP Stored Procedure Calls

Tags: stored-procedures, asp-classic

I'm using the following code block to call a SQL Server 2005 stored procedure. The problem is the call will intermittently fail. How can I obtain more verbose information about the case of the failure. I've tested the SP with the failing input and found no issues. This would seems to indicate an error on the ASP side.

```
Set rsOrderItems = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rsOrderItems.ActiveConnection = MM_SkateSeason_Connect
rsOrderItems.CursorType = 0
rsOrderItems.CursorLocation = 2
rsOrderItems.LockType = 1
rsOrderItems.Source = "{call dbo.upOrder_InsertNew('" & MM_OrderString & "')}"
on error resume next   
rsOrderItems.Open


if (rsOrderItems.State) then
else
    FAILS HERE
    InsertOrder = "Order Failed. 2"
end if
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Connection object has an Errors collection you can spin through:

```
For Each errorObject In MM_SkateSeason_Connect.Errors
    Debug.Print "Description :"; errorObject.Description
    Debug.Print "Number:"; errorObject.Number
Next
```